# Lambda function with undefined number of arguments

Tags: racket, lambda

I need to create a function which takes any number of argumnets and returns a comma-separated string of those elements.

E.g.

```
(comma-separated-list 1 2 3)
;=> "1 , 2 , 3"
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
(define (comma-separated-list x . xs)
  (begin
    (display x)
    (when (not (null? xs))
      (begin
        (display " , ")
        (comma-separated-list xs)))))
```

But this is not properly working.

As an example:

```
(comma-separated-list 1 2 3)
```

returns the string:

```
1 , (2 3)
```

while I want it to return:

```
1, 2, 3
```

How can I implement it?

Comment: "this is not properly working." What is it doing?  What isn't it doing? What did you expect it do to?

Comment: I edited the question according to your advices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code:

```
(define (comma-separated-list x . xs) ; (a) can accept any number of arguments
  (begin
    (display x)                       ; (b) print the first argument 
    (when (not (null? xs))
      (begin
        (display " , ")
        (comma-separated-list xs))))) ; (c) a call with just one argument
```

After your first call `(comma-separated-list 1 2 3)`, your recursive call on line `(c)` is equivalent to

```
(comma-separated-list '(2 3))
```

which has just a single argument, not two arguments.  You need to [`apply`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/private/base..rkt%29._apply%29%29) `comma-separated-list` to the remaining arguments instead:

```
(apply comma-separated-list xs)
```

### Other Notes

As an aside, there's a difference between what you said you want, what you showed in the desired output, and what your code will generate.  Your initial example was

```
(comma-separated-list 1 2 3)
;=> "1 , 2 , 3"
```

where there are spaces before the commas, and that's what you'll get with

```
(display " , ")
```

but then in the edit, you said that you wanted

```
1, 2, 3
```

It's easy to get one or the other (just adjust the spaces), but be aware of the difference!

Answer (score 3):

You could simply use `string-join`:

```
(define (comma-separated-list . lst)
  (string-join 
   (map (lambda (e) (format "~a" e)) lst) 
   ", "))
```

then

```
(comma-separated-list 1 2 3)
=> "1, 2, 3"
```

Comment: Even shorter: `(define (comma-separated-list . lst) (string-join (map ~a lst) ", "))`